# Scroll Bar in Popup : no horizontal scroll bar by default but enable scroll bar when content is big

Tags: javascript, html, popup

I have popup window named Search Popup. 
I understood, to enable popup with scrollbar, we can achieve by scrollbar = yes. 
But My Popup window's content is not big by default, after submit functionality in popup, 
it will throw data in the popup. So that time I need popup with scroll.

My Question is How to enable scrollbar when the content is big and disable scrollbar when the content is fit within popup? Can you please help me on this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to open a new browser window.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">With Maximize</button>

<script>

function myFunction() {
   var leftCornerX = screen.width/2 - 820/2;
var leftCornerY = screen.height/2 - 480/2;
    window.open("Search Popup","Sample Popup","scrollbars=yes,status=no,resizable=no,width=820,height=480,left= "+leftCornerX +",top="+leftCornerY);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
overflow:auto;
```

in your css

Comment: But Popup will open using window.open(),how I'll achieve this in css?

Comment: @Makz23.Popup will open by link(<a></a>) using window.open(). How I'll achieve this in css? Can you please help me

Comment: Can you access to your popup css? You can try in window.open() arguments maybe.